# Cast Exception occuring on Window 7 but not on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, casting, windows-10

So I have code that should throw a cast exception

```
public double LengthInM { get { return Conversions.FtoM(((equipment)Item).TotalVolumeInL); } }
```

The item variable is an instance of a siteItem class, is being deserialized from a file, and in this case is casting to the wrong type of siteItem. A cast exception should be thrown but isn't on my machine.  On a coworkers machine the cast exception is thrown.

They are running windows 7 while I am running windows 10.  We've both installed Visual Studio off the same package but our versions of Visual Studio still have tiny differences, but more to the point, why would identical versions of Visual Studio and slightly different versions of .NET cause cast exceptions to stop being thrown?

My .NET is 4.6.01586.
Their .NET is 4.6.01055

Comment: I think you're going to need to add a lot more detail.

Comment: What kind of details?

Comment: Implementations of the other methods in that line of code.

Comment: The program doesn't enter those methods before the cast error occurs.  The issue is with '(equipment) item' cast.  I could just well as say 'Foo f = (Foo) b;' is throwing a cast exception on one machine and not another.  What possible cause is there to that?

Comment: Then you gotta show us the impelmentations of `Item` and `equipment` :)